# Is this kind of function calls permissible in C

Tags: c, function, undefined-behavior

```
char* p = init();
p = foo(p);        /* this one */
```

the function `foo` prototype:

```
char* foo(char* p);
```

Is it permissible to call `foo` that way, or does it fall in the **Undefined Behavior** category?

Comment: yes it's fine to do that. The right hand is evaluated before assignment

Comment: Why would it be undefined behaviour?

Comment: Why would it cause undefined behavior?

Comment: @AR7 This is not a good justification. `i=i++;` is UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well yes, but that's not what they were asking and I'm not going to be that comprehensive in a comment.

Comment: `*p = foo(p)` can be *UB* if `char foo(char* p);` and modifying the pointee.

Comment: Do you mean `char* p = foo(p)`? As written it's the responsibility of `init()` to properly populate `p`.

Comment: @tadman what about `char* p = foo(p)`, is it UB?

Comment: @BiteBytes, yes, `char* p = foo(p)` exhibits undefined behavior, because it attempts to use the value of `p` before `p` is initialized (indeed, in `p`'s own initializer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is well-defined - there is a sequence point between the evaluation of the function arguments and the function call.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it permissible to call foo that way, or does it fall in the Undefined Behavior category?

**Yes** it is, the order is guaranteed (a sequence point exists between the parameters' evaluation and the function call).

---

You are probably confusing that with *side-effects* of unsequenced modifications or something.

Comment: Or with *side-effects* of unsequenced modifications.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say @DavidC.Rankin, thank you!